# Bounding a $C^0$ function with $C^1$ functions

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

> Given a continuous function from $(0,+\infty)$ in itself, with $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x)=0$, find $C^1$ functions $g,h:(0,+\infty)\longrightarrow(0,+\infty)$ such that $g\leq f\leq h$ and $\lim_{x\to 0^+}h(x)=0$.

More in general, suggestions about "smoothing" functions (or something less, $C^k$ or $C^1$ like in this case) are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varphi:\mathbb R\to [0,1]$ be $C^\infty$ with support in $[0,1],$ and assume $\int_0^1 \varphi = 1.$ Define $\psi(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x \varphi.$ Then $\psi\in C^\infty,$ $0\le \psi \le 1$ everywhere, $\psi=0 $ on $(-\infty,0],$ $\psi = 1$ on $[1,\infty).$ We can think of this $\psi$ as a smooth interpolation from $0$ to $1.$

By looking at functions of the form $a + b \psi((x-c)/d)$ we can smoothly interpolate any values we like, at any locations we like, and at any rate we like. This allows for the smooth interpolation of any step function, even one with infinitely many values.

So given your continuous $f,$ choose sequences $1 = a_1 > a_2 > \dots \to 0,$ and $1=b_1 < b_2 < \cdots \to \infty.$ Let

$$A_n = \sup_{[a_{n+1},a_n)} f, B_n = \sup_{[b_n,b_{n+1})}f.$$

An appropriate smooth interpolation of these values will give you $h;$ you can do the same thing with the infimums, giving $g.$